# Operator-norm Identity (inequalitity)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

in our lecture for functional-analysis we defined the norm of a linear operator as
$$||T||:=||T||_{X\rightarrow Y}=\inf\{C\geq0|\forall x\in X:~||Tx||_Y\leq C||x||_X\}$$
and then we said it is:
$$||T||_{X\rightarrow Y}\geq \sup_{x\neq0}\frac{||Tx||_Y}{||x||_X}\geq \sup_{||x||\leq1}||Tx||_Y\geq \sup_{||x||=1}||Tx||_Y$$
and i have problems understanding why theese inequalties hold and especially why the first one is not already an equality.
Could someone maybe give me hint on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are all equalities. The point is that the inequalities are trivial to prove (details below), and so all that remains to obtain the equalities  is to show that
$$
\sup_{\|x \|=1}\|Tx \|\geq \|T\|.
$$

---

**Proofs of the inequalities.**

Suppose that $C$ satisfies $\|Tx\|\leq C\|x\|$ for all $x$. Then, for any $x\ne0$ we have $\|Tx\|/\|x\|\leq C$. So
$$
\sup_{x\ne0}\frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}\leq C. 
$$
As this holds for any such bound $C$,
$$\tag1
\sup_{x\ne0}\frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}\leq\inf\{C:\ \|Tx\|\leq\|x\|\}=\|T\|. 
$$
For the second inequality, if $x\ne0$ then
$$
\frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}=\|Ty\|
$$
where $y=x/\|x\|$ and $\|y\|\leq1$. This shows the second inequality.

Finally,
$$
\sup_{\|x\|\leq1}\|Tx\|\geq\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Tx\|
$$
simply because the set on the left contains the set on the right.

Comment: Yes that is exaxtly the way we showed the equality. But i really cannot see why these trivial inequalitites hold.

Comment: I have added some detail.

Comment: Okay now I see. Thank you!